# jQuery remove class not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a lightbox effect for a site that uses informational pop-ups when a certain `ID` is clicked.  The site is very large so the code I've added below has been trimmed of anything excess.  I'm trying to get `.overlay` to show up by removing `.hidden` when I click on `#box1`.  Something is wrong with my jQuery code, but I'm not sure what since I'm terrible at it.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HNWK6/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="box1">Click Me</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="overlay" class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{height:200px;background:#CCC;}
#content{height:200px;background:blue;}
#footer{height:200px;background:red;}
#box1{height:50px; width:50px; background:#0F0;position:absolute; left:300px;top:400px;}
#overlay{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:visible;background:#90F;}
.hidden{display:none;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#box1").click(function(e) {
        $("#overlay").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is actually loading? It's not in the fiddle.... Add it and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/5Sqzp/1/

Comment: Yep, your fiddle is not using jquery. But your code work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jsfiddle works when you include jQuery so I assume the problem relys on the inclution of jQuery.